# C# problem with files which I upload to my FTP

Tags: c#, ftp

I have  very strange problem when I upload  files to my FTP (zip or gif)  files.

I am creating a zip file with code and upload it with code to FTP. I can open any of this  files type when I create them on my local disk. But when I upload any of this to FTP and than download it show me a message for .zip file as "unexpected end of archive" ,  and  for .gif file type after I download them and try to open in XP Windows picture and fax viewer "Drawing failed" :

I  use this code for uploading to FTP:

```
 FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.tim.com/" + fileName);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpuser,ftppass);

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(filePath +"\\"+ fileName);
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
            request.KeepAlive = false;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();
```

Comment: Encoding.UTF8 is a text encoding, you are trying to read a binary stream in text hence the issue.

Comment: Yes   :)  You are right Mike .. I didn't saw this  line :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code:

```
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(filePath +"\\"+ fileName);
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
```

You're reading the bytestream as text with a specific encoding (UTF8)... but GIF and ZIP are binary files, not text files. The encoding is mangling them.

Try using something like [ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx):

```
byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes("filepath");
```

Comment: Work for me. Thks pro :)

Answer (score 3):

You are reading binary data to string (assuming it utf8) and converts it back to bytes array. That's completely wrong.

Comment: +1 - try using `byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(path)` instead.